# Oracle wallet manager - how do allow access to oracle wallet for a user who did not create the wallet?

Tags: oracle-wallet

I created a wallet using oracle wallet manager. The wallet is password secured and uses auto login. Currently, The only way the developer is able to use the wallet is by changing the file permissions to the sso file and setting it to read. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Tried adding user to the different ORA_* Groups.
Tried giving permissions to sso file (this one works).
Running as admin (Works, but would like to avoid this case for code.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.